# ¿Converitr un array de objetos con clave y valor diferentes a un array?

Tags: javascript, array, objeto

gracias de ante mano por sus respuestas y comentarios quiero transformar un array de objetos en un array, teniendo en el array la clave y valor de cada objeto, enexo el código para explicarme un poco mejor.
Tengo el siguiente array de objetos:

```
var data = [
  {id: 1, nombre: 'Darinel', genero: 'Masculino', table: 'catalogos_genero'},
  {id: 2, nomrbe: 'Kitsia', genero: 'Femenino', table: 'catalogo_genero'},
  {id: 1, nombre_cp: 'Yair', puesto: 'Desarrollador', table:'catalogo_puestos'}
];
```

De este array de objetos estoy intentando obtener algo como lo siguiente:

```
var data2 = [
  'catalogo_genero: Darinel Masculino',
  'catalogo_genero: Kitsia Femenino',
  'catalogo_puestos: Yair Desarrollador',
];
```

El array de objetos puede variar su contenido como expongo en el ejemplo la clave y valor no siempre seran los mismos, lo que busco es crear la estructura de data2 sin importar las propiedades de los objetos.

Estoy intentando de esta manera:

```
Object.values(data).map(({ genero }) => (`genero: ${genero}`))
```

El problema de esto es que siempre espero la propiedad genero y los objetos varian sus propiedades, les agradeceria mucho cualquier tipo de ayuda o sugerencia para resolver mi problema, muchas gracias de nuevo.

**Se me olvidaba mencionar que la propiedad table siempre va a existir en los objetos aun que su valor sea diferente pero estara presente siempre.**

Comment: Crea un "parseador" para cada tipo de "table". Suponiendo que todos los elementos con igual "table" tienen siempre la misma estructura.

Comment: Siempre serán 4 keyes y necesitamos los valores de la 4ta, 2da y 3ra?, es decir independiente de que en alguna ocasión pueda decir genero o puesto, siempre serán 4 grupos de clave/valor en el objeto?

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo Investigare sobre el tema gracias por tu aporte.

Comment: @LuisS.Romero No siempre seran 4 keyes , esto también puede variar el objeto puede tener N propiedades.

Comment: @LuisS.Romero El orden en que se estructura en el array no importa solo la key table debe ir primero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con un array así, podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
var data = [
  { id: 1, nombre: "Darinel", genero: "Masculino", table: "catalogos_genero" },
  { id: 2, nomrbe: "Kitsia", genero: "Femenino", table: "catalogo_genero" },
  {
    id: 1,
    nombre_cp: "Yair",
    puesto: "Desarrollador",
    table: "catalogo_puestos",
  },
];
```

Luego llamaríamos a la función y le pasaríamos data ej:

```
dataInArrays(data)
```

**Opción 1a**

```
function dataInArrays(data) {
  const result = [];
  for (const obj of data) {
    const objInArray = Object.values(obj);
    result.push(`${objInArray[3]}: ${objInArray[1]} ${objInArray[2]}`);
  }
  return result;
}
```

**Opción 2a**

```
data.map((obj) => {
  const objInArray = Object.values(obj);
  return `${objInArray[3]}: ${objInArray[1]} ${objInArray[2]}`;
});
```

Espero te sirva, tal cual comentaban en los comentarios, y la razón por la que te pregunté si la estructura es siempre la misma es porque estamos jugando con la posición de cada valor dentro del objeto para obtenerlos y mostrarlos como deseamos.

---

Agrego ejemplos con estructura dinámica, sabiendo que siempre existe un **table**

**Opción 1b**

```
function dataInArrays(data) {
  const result = [];
  for (const obj of data) {
    let stringFromSTR = obj.table  + ": ";
    for (const key in obj) {
      if (key !== "table" && key !== "id") stringFromSTR += " " + obj[key];
    }
    result.push(stringFromSTR);
  }
  return result;
}
```

**Opción 2b**

```
data.map((obj) => {
  let stringFromSTR = obj.table + ": ";
  for (const key in obj) {
    if (key !== "table" && key !== "id") stringFromSTR += " " + obj[key];
  }
  return stringFromSTR;
});
```

Comment: Hola como siempre salvando mi día te agradezco mucho la respuesta, funciona perfectamente, me ha surgido una duda en caso de que sean más de 4 keyes eso fallaría ¿Cierto? ¿Como podría imprimir N keyes?

Comment: El problema es que el orden de las keys no está garantizado. Y en general es mala práctica.

Comment: Tendría que hacer un for de ObjeInArray y jugar con los objetos retornados ¿Estoy en lo correcto?

Comment: Los ejemplos 1b y 2b, están formandose con un forIn dentro de cada objeto, lo que hago es primero creo un str con solo el valor de table y luego concateno los otros, por lo que si además de table y id que lo saqué de la lista... Si además de ellos hay 3 o 19 keys más, los agregaría sin problema. Los ejemplos 1a y 2a, solo funcionan si la estructura es de esos 4 elementos. Agregué el caso dinámico a la respuesta al final, siempre es un placer ayudar, confirmame si funcionó por favor, para quedarnos tranquilos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por actualizar tu respuesta y la explicación.

Comment: A las órdenes estimado!

Comment: Yo me refería a algo así: ``const formatters = { catalogo_genero: ({ nombre, genero, table }) => `...`, catalogo_puestos: ({ nombre_cp, puesto, table }) => `...` }

data.map(el => formatters[el.table](el));``